# Erro ao converter imagem para String para salvar no banco

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, upload

Estou tentanto salvar uma imagem em meu formulário no banco, porém estou com dificuldades na resolução do erro:

> Field error in object 'usuario' on field 'foto': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@2218206a]; codes [typeMismatch.usuario.foto,typeMismatch.foto,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [usuario.foto,foto]; arguments []; default message [foto]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'foto': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a salvar imagem no banco Mysql, utilizando o Spring boot?

Meu model `Usuario`:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String foto;


    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }
}
```

O controller para salvar o form:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ModelAndView save(@Valid Usuario usuario, String senhaconf, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, String senha, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    if (result.hasErrors() || !senha.equals(senhaconf)) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "[Verifique os campos!");
        System.out.println("--------erro ao salvar: " + usuario.getId());
        return cadastrarFornecedor(usuario);
    }
    String foto = files[0].getOriginalFilename();
    usuario.setFoto(foto);
    usuario.setSenha(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(senha));
    service.save(usuario);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Evento cadastrado com sucesso!");
    return findAll();
}
```

Comment: Veja se esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48147137/4319922) lhe ajuda.

Comment: nao ajudou @StatelessDev, vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente alterar `@RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[]`  para `@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[]`